# Play 2 framework unit tests, EBean, PostgreSQL - java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, ebean

I'm using Play 2.3, PostgreSQL and EBean. The application is on Java.
I'm trying to run my unit tests and getting this error:
"java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?"

I've checked, the "db.default.user" and "db.default.password" properties are used (like in some answers to similar problems).

This string is also present in the application.conf file:

ebean.default="models.*"

I also tried to set username and password in the DB connection URL and I still get this error.
What else can be wrong?

Comment: Do you start a fake application with your configuration for your unit tests?

Comment: The fakeApplication() method is called with a HashMap of settings as a parameter.

Comment: Would be helpful for others with the same problem to know how it got fixed.